# TikZ get value of passed option/key inside pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-pic

Is it possible to access the options that are passed to a pic inside the definition of a pic?
And if yes, how?

I know I can do this with self-defined custom keys.
But is it possible to also get the values that were passed to default TikZ/PGF keys; for example "scale" or "rotation"?

So the following works well and fine (custom key):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
  myArg/.initial=1,
  pics/PassPic/.style={code={
    \tikzset{myArg/.get=\AquisitionVarOne}
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/myArg}{\AquisitionVarTwo}%
    \newcommand{\AquisitionVarThree}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/myArg}}
    \path[draw=black](0,0)circle(0.5);
    \node()at(0,0){\AquisitionVarOne - \AquisitionVarTwo - \AquisitionVarThree};
  }},
}

\pic(testPic)[scale=2,myArg=3]{PassPic};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But what I actually would like to have is the same thing for options that are passed to out-of-the-box default keys, like "scale":

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{%
  pics/PassPic/.style={code={
    \tikzset{scale/.get=\PassedScale}
    \path[draw=black](0,0)circle(0.5);
    \node()at(0,0){Passed Scale: \PassedScale};
  }},
}

\pic(testPic)[scale=2]{PassPic};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I also tried different expressions for the key, like "/tikz/scale", "/pgf/scale/" and I tried it with other keys like "rotation" or "draw". But I can't seem to access any.

Comment: Yes, the [style `pic actions`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-pics#pgf./tikz/pic:actions) inherits all options that are passed to the pic. You can't extract the values that easily, since options like `scale` add a transformation and don't just store their value somewhere.

Comment: Thank you. I finally created a kind-of dirty workaround. I introduced a "Wrapper Pic" to which I pass a custom key, which is then read inside. Then the wrapper posts the actual Pic with the value for the actual default-key.